# Angular mat-select not styling correctly with multiple

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular 13 application, and am using Angular Material.  My problem is that the mat-select control doesn't look correct with the multiple option.

My code:

.ts

```
toppings = new FormControl('');
toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Toppings single</mat-label>
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Toppings multiple</mat-label>
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Result:

[image]

Why is that inner rectangle showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the select styling was being changed by the tailwind css forms module.  I've removed that module and all is now ok.

Answer (score 0):

It could be `outline` or `border` or `box-shadow`.

You can disable it with:

```
select.no-outline{
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}

<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple ngClass="no-outline">
```